# How to access and display nested object property when click on an user image and goes to detail page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

I am fetching a list of items from a local `Data.js` file and displaying it using `map` method in `Header.js`. But when I click on user image then it should go to user detail page and should display all the properties of that object. But when I click it gives me error saying "`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')`". I am using `react-router-domv6`.

Users.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { list } from './Data';

function Header() {
  console.log(list);
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="bg-gradient-to-b from-white-300 to-[#6337c8] relative flex justify-center items-center h-screen w-screen">
        <div className="absolute top-0 w-full z-[-1]">
          <div className="h-[20vh] bg-[#6337c8]"></div>
          <svg className="drop-shadow-[0px_17px_0px_#dcd6f3] z-[-1]" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320">
            <path
              fill="#6337c8"
              fillOpacity={1}
              d="M 0 224 L 80 197.3 C 160 171 320 117 480 128 C 640 139 800 213 960 245.3 C 1120 277 1280 267 1360 261.3 L 1440 256 L 1440 0 L 1360 0 C 1280 0 1120 0 960 0 C 800 0 640 0 480 0 C 320 0 160 0 80 0 L 0 0 Z"
            ></path>
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div className="h-[85vh] shadow-2xl w-2/5 rounded-[25px] bg-white">
          <div className="w-full rounded-t-[25px] flex justify-center items-center h-[16vh] text-gray-600 bg-gray-100 text-xl">
            {' '}
            Select an account{' '}
          </div>
          <div className="h-[65vh] pb-4 px7 overflow-y-auto scrollbar scrollbar-thumb-gray-200">
            {list &&
              list.length > 0 &&
              list.map((value) => (
                <Link key={value.id} to={`/profile/${value.id}`}>
                  <div className="cursor-pointer flex gap-3 items-center border-b py-2">
                    <img className="rounded-full w-[7%]" src={value.profilepicture} alt="" />
                    <p>City: {value.address.city}</p>
                    <p>Company Name: {value.company.name}</p>
                    <div className="text-md text-gray-700 text-center font-[400] ">
                      <button>{value.name}</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </Link>
              ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

UserDetail.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { list } from './Data';

function Profile() {
  const [item, setItem] = useState({});
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const { id } = useParams();

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    getItem();
  }, []);

  const getItem = () => {
    const newItem = list.find((value) => value.id === parseInt(id));
    setItem(newItem);
  };

  const Logout = () => {
    navigate('/');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="w-screen h-screen flex gap-10 px-8 pt-3 overflow-x-hidden">
        <div className="flex flex-col w-full">
          <div className="h-[13vh] w-[100%] border-b border-gray-300">
            <div className="flex h-full items-center justify-between">
              <div className="capitalize text-[20px] text-gray-500">
                <p>profile</p>
              </div>

              <div className="relative inline-block text-left mt-5 ml-40" data-headlessui-state>
                {
                  <div>
                    <button
                      className="inline-flex w-full justify-center rounded-md bg-white px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 shadow-sm focus:outline-none "
                      id="headlessui-menu-button-:r0:"
                      type="button"
                      aria-haspopup="menu"
                      aria-expanded="false"
                      data-headlessui-state="open"
                      aria-controls="headlessui-menu-items-:r1:"
                      onClick={() => setShow(!show)}
                    >
                      <div className="cursor-pointer flex justify-end gap-3 items-center">
                        <img className="rounded-full w-[7%]" src={item.profilepicture} alt={item.id} />
                        <p>{item.name}</p>
                      </div>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                }

                {show && (
                  <div
                    className="absolute right-0 z-10 mt-2 w-[20vw] origin-top-right rounded-md bg-white shadow-lg focus:outline-none transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                    aria-labelledby="headlessui-menu-button-:r0:"
                    id="headlessui-menu-items-:r7:"
                    role="menu"
                    tabIndex={0}
                    data-headlessui-state="open"
                  >
                    <div className=" py-1" role="none">
                      <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center gap-1 pb-2 " role="none">
                        <img className="rounded-full" src={item.profilepicture} alt="" width="50%" role="none"></img>
                        <p role="none">{item.name}</p>
                        <p className="text-[14px] text-gray-400" role="none">
                          {item.email}
                        </p>
                        <div className="border-t border-gray-300 ">
                          <button className="mt-2 rounded-[20px] px-2 py-1 text-white bg-[#e15b22]" role="none" onClick={Logout}>
                            Sign out
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="block">
            <div className="w-full h-full flex mt-5">
              <div className="border-r border-gray-300 h-full w-[40%]">
                {
                  <div className="flex flex-col w-full items-center h-full justify-center">
                    <img className="rounded-full w-[48%]" src={item.profilepicture} alt="" />
                    <p className="text-[16px] font-[400] text-gray-800">{item.name}</p>

                    <div className="flex flex-col gap-2 border-b border-gray-300 py-3">
                      <div className="flex gap-3 items-center justify-center">
                        <p className="text-[16px] font-[400] text-gray-400">Username:</p>
                        <p className="text-[16px] font-[400] text-gray-800">{item.username}</p>
                      </div>

                      <div className="flex gap-3 items-center justify-center">
                        <p className="text-[16px] font-[400] text-gray-400">email:</p>
                        <p className="text-[16px] font-[400] text-gray-800">{item.email}</p>
                      </div>

                      <div className="flex gap-3 items-center justify-center">
                        <p className="text-[16px] font-[400] text-gray-400">phoneNumber:</p>
                        <p className="text-[16px] font-[400] text-gray-800">{item.phone}</p>
                      </div>
                      <div className="flex gap-3 items-center justify-center">
                        <p className="text-[16px] font-[400] text-gray-400">website:</p>
                        <p className="text-[16px] font-[400] text-gray-800">{item.website}</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="flex flex-col gap-2 py-3">
                      <div className="flex gap-3 items-center justify-center">
                        <p className="text-[16px] font-[400] text-gray-400">company:</p>
                        <p className="text-[16px] font-[400] text-gray-800">{item.company.name}</p>
                      </div>

                      <div className="flex gap-3 items-center justify-center">
                        <p className="text-[16px] font-[400] text-gray-400">bs:</p>
                        <p className="text-[16px] font-[400] text-gray-800">{item.company.bs}</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                }
              </div>

              <div className="h-full w-[60%]">
                <div className="flex gap-3 items-center justify-center">
                  <p className="text-[16px] font-[400] text-gray-400">address:</p>

                  <p className="text-[16px] font-[400] text-gray-800">{item.address.city}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Profile;
```

Data.js

```js
export const list = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: ' Leanne Graham',
    username: 'Bret',
    email: 'Sincere@april.biz',
    profilepicture: 'https://panorbit.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/hotlink-ok/1001.jpeg',
    address: {
      street: 'Kulas Light',
      suite: 'Apt. 556',
      city: 'Gwenborough',
      zipcode: '92998-3874',
      geo: {
        lat: '-37.3159',
        lng: '81.1496',
      },
    },
    phone: '1-770-736-8031 x56442',
    website: 'hildegard.org',
    company: {
      name: 'Romaguera-Crona',
      catchPhrase: 'Multi-layered client-server neural-net',
      bs: 'harness real-time e-markets',
    },
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: ' Ervin Howell',
    username: 'Antonette',
    email: 'Shanna@melissa.tv',
    profilepicture: 'https://panorbit.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/hotlink-ok/1002.jpeg',
    address: {
      street: 'Victor Plains',
      suite: 'Suite 879',
      city: 'Wisokyburgh',
      zipcode: '90566-7771',
      geo: {
        lat: '-43.9509',
        lng: '-34.4618',
      },
    },
    phone: '010-692-6593 x09hotlink-ok5',
    website: 'anastasia.net',
    company: {
      name: 'Deckow-Crist',
      catchPhrase: 'Proactive didactic contingency',
      bs: 'synergize scalable supply-chains',
    },
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in the `Profile` component the initial `item` state is an empty object `{}` which is fine when only accessing root-level properties, i.e. `item.name`, `item.company`, etc, but the issue is that during the initial render cycle and any subsequent render cycle until the `item` state is populated all the root-level properties will be undefined, so an error is thrown when attempting to access a second-level property like `item.company.name`. `item.company` is undefined and attempting to access `item.company.name` will throw the exception.

The `item` "state" is completely unnecessary as it's what we would call derived state, in that it is derived from the current `id` route path parameter and the imported `list` array. Derived state shouldn't be stored in local state unless absolutely necessary.

To resolve the issue simply compute the `item` value from the `list` and `id` values. I recommend also converting the data's `id` property to a String instead of parsing the route path parameter to an integer as it's generally easier to compare number-like strings.

Example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { list } from './Data';

function Profile() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { id } = useParams();

  const item = list.find((value) => String(value.id) === id);

  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const Logout = () => {
    navigate('/');
  };

  if (!item) {
    // No matching item found, render nothing, error message, etc, it's up to you
    return <div>No matching item found.</div>;

  }

  return (
    <div>
      ....
    </div>
  );
}
```

If the "cost" of computing the `item` value is "expensive" you can memoize the value with the `useMemo` hook.

```js
const item = useMemo(() => {
  return list.find((value) => String(value.id) === id)
}, [id]);
```

In fact, just about any time you see you've implemented the pattern `useState` + `useEffect` you should really be using `useMemo`.

Comment: @meatstackoverflow Certainly, glad to help. Cheers and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the initial state value to `const [item, getItem] = useState(null);` and then check if the item exists, render the data otherwise not.

Please replace you `UserDetail.js` file that file which I updated in my answer.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { list } from './Data';

function Profile() {
  const [item, setItem] = useState(null);
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const { id } = useParams();

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    getItem();
  }, []);

  const getItem = () => {
    const newItem = list.find((value) => value.id === parseInt(id));
    setItem(newItem);
  };

  const Logout = () => {
    navigate('/');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="w-screen h-screen flex gap-10 px-8 pt-3 overflow-x-hidden">
        <div className="flex flex-col w-full">
          <div className="h-[13vh] w-[100%] border-b border-gray-300">
            <div className="flex h-full items-center justify-between">
              <div className="capitalize text-[20px] text-gray-500">
                <p>profile</p>
              </div>

              <div className="relative inline-block text-left mt-5 ml-40" data-headlessui-state>
                {item &&
                  <div>
                    <button
                      className="inline-flex w-full justify-center rounded-md bg-white px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 shadow-sm focus:outline-none "
                      id="headlessui-menu-button-:r0:"
                      type="button"
                      aria-haspopup="menu"
                      aria-expanded="false"
                      data-headlessui-state="open"
                      aria-controls="headlessui-menu-items-:r1:"
                      onClick={() => setShow(!show)}
                    >
                      <div className="cursor-pointer flex justify-end gap-3 items-center">
                        <img className="rounded-full w-[7%]" src={item.profilepicture} alt={item.id} />
                        <p>{item.name}</p>
                      </div>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                }

                {show && (
                  <div
                    className="absolute right-0 z-10 mt-2 w-[20vw] origin-top-right rounded-md bg-white shadow-lg focus:outline-none transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                    aria-labelledby="headlessui-menu-button-:r0:"
                    id="headlessui-menu-items-:r7:"
                    role="menu"
                    tabIndex={0}
                    data-headlessui-state="open"
                  >
                    <div className=" py-1" role="none">
                      <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center gap-1 pb-2 " role="none">
                        <img className="rounded-full" src={item.profilepicture} alt="" width="50%" role="none"></img>
                        <p role="none">{item.name}</p>
                        <p className="text-[14px] text-gray-400" role="none">
                          {item.email}
                        </p>
                        <div className="border-t border-gray-300 ">
                          <button className="mt-2 rounded-[20px] px-2 py-1 text-white bg-[#e15b22]" role="none" onClick={Logout}>
                            Sign out
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="block">
            <div className="w-full h-full flex mt-5">
              <div className="border-r border-gray-300 h-full w-[40%]">
                {item &&
                  <div className="flex flex-col w-full items-center h-full justify-center">
                    <img className="rounded-full w-[48%]" src={item.profilepicture} alt="" />
                    <p className="text-[16px] font-[400] text-gray-800">{item.name}</p>

                    <div className="flex flex-col gap-2 border-b border-gray-300 py-3">
                      <div className="flex gap-3 items-center justify-center">
                        <p className="text-[16px] font-[400] text-gray-400">Username:</p>
                        <p className="text-[16px] font-[400] text-gray-800">{item.username}</p>
                      </div>

                      <div className="flex gap-3 items-center justify-center">
                        <p className="text-[16px] font-[400] text-gray-400">email:</p>
                        <p className="text-[16px] font-[400] text-gray-800">{item.email}</p>
                      </div>

                      <div className="flex gap-3 items-center justify-center">
                        <p className="text-[16px] font-[400] text-gray-400">phoneNumber:</p>
                        <p className="text-[16px] font-[400] text-gray-800">{item.phone}</p>
                      </div>
                      <div className="flex gap-3 items-center justify-center">
                        <p className="text-[16px] font-[400] text-gray-400">website:</p>
                        <p className="text-[16px] font-[400] text-gray-800">{item.website}</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="flex flex-col gap-2 py-3">
                      <div className="flex gap-3 items-center justify-center">
                        <p className="text-[16px] font-[400] text-gray-400">company:</p>
                        <p className="text-[16px] font-[400] text-gray-800">{item.company.name}</p>
                      </div>

                      <div className="flex gap-3 items-center justify-center">
                        <p className="text-[16px] font-[400] text-gray-400">bs:</p>
                        <p className="text-[16px] font-[400] text-gray-800">{item.company.bs}</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                }
              </div>

              <div className="h-full w-[60%]">
                <div className="flex gap-3 items-center justify-center">
                  <p className="text-[16px] font-[400] text-gray-400">address:</p>

                  <p className="text-[16px] font-[400] text-gray-800">{item?.address?.city}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Profile;
```

Comment: This will still throw a error saying that `name` does not exist on `item` since the `item` is null

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-fast-qf5l22?file=/src/App.js

Comment: check this link, here is the live example

Comment: Hmm I stand corrected! I totally missed the `{item && (` syntax

Answer (score 0):

Your initial state is a empty object `{}` which means the property `name` is not defined yet.

To resolve this you can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

```js
<p>{item?.name}</p>
```

Same for all the other expression which use `item`.

Now for the `useEffect`, this will currently only ran the very first render. But will not update once you revisit to check another user. To fix this you can pass the `id` as a dependency.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  getItem();
}, [id]);
```